# Can I create a generic hyperlink without a href?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a MySQL database with names of fruit. PHP then reads this and creates a list of them on a web page. At the moment, I have added individual URLs for each type of fruit so that readers can get more information about that particular fruit.

I was wondering though if I could create one generic web page called, say fruitinfo.php that read information from the database about whichever fruit the user clicked on. The problem I have is that I am not sure how to record in a variable which fruit the user clicked on. Also, the only way I know to make a "link" clickable is to use a href, which I do not want to do. Is what I am hoping to be able to do possible?

Comment: Its possible, give us some example code we will help you write rest

Comment: Sounds like you want AJAX, read about that.

Comment: Hang on, are you telling me that at the moment you have separate PHP files for all fruit?

Comment: Add a query string to each url. Eg ?fruit=apple. In your php check the $_GET['fruit'] variable to find which link the user clicked.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking do you want to maybe use GET by appending which fruit was clicked on onto the url? ie href="fruitinfo.php?fruit=mango"

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want, but using an href is simplest. You can do it all with one php page. e.g. fruit.php

First you get your data from the database, and you create the elements you wish the user to click on in order to get more info, e.g. a word like Apple. Then wrap the word in an anchor tag for that fruit and add a query string to the href eg.

`<a href="fruit.php?fruit=apple">Apple</a>`

When the user clicks on it, they'll be sent back to your php page. You can check the global $_GET variable to see what fruit they clicked on. Since you don't know if they're sending a fruit back to you or not, you should check to see if the variable is set. You can do it like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['fruit']) {
 //do something
}
```

Alternatively, more complex methods which don't use the href would include making an ajax call, or getting all the data in the first instance in something like a JSON object. The easiest out of these would be to use jQuery and make an ajax call. If you're interested in this, or anyone else is, let me know and I'll write an explanation for it and the requisite code.

Comment: Ill add more detail when I have a mo. Just putting my son to bed.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example

Fruit Database

```
|- id -|- name   -|- detail    -|
|-  1 -|- apple  -|- Delicious -|
|-  2 -|- orange -|- Its orange |
```

Main page (We will generate it from server)

```
Links
<a href="detail.php?id=1">Apple</a>
<a href="detail.php?id=2">Orange</a>
or
<a href="detail.php?name=apple">Apple</a>
<a href="detail.php?name=orange">Orange</a>
```

Detail page

```
$fruit = $_GET['name']

// Query fruit by id or name from server

// Print fruit details
```

Comment: Below is part of the script I have written. I modified it now to try to generate links that the GET function can use. Unfortunately, whereas the script worked before, it no longer generates the list of names. I am not sure at the moment what I have done wrong.

Comment: Here is the script: $result = mysql_query("SELECT fruit, fruit_link FROM fruit_types ORDER BY fruit");

$column_count = 1;

echo "<table align=center><th>Categories</th>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($column_count == 1) echo "<tr>";
if ($column_count <= 3) echo "<td colspan=200>";
echo "<a href=".'"'."http://www.mydomain.com/fruitinfo.php?=".str_replace($row['fruit']," ","_")."</a>";
if ($column_count <= 3) echo "</td>";
if ($column_count == 3) echo "</tr>";
if ($column_count == 3) $column_count = 0;
$column_count = $column_count + 1;
};

Comment: @user2399553 Would be better to move the script to the main question. And imho also to rename your question from "Can I create a generic hyperlink without a href?" to something like "How to send data from page visitor to server"

Comment: I agree with @Stano write your script to question